# Принадлежность точки многоугольнику

Tags: алгоритм, математика, инспекция-кода, геометрия

Есть код, который проверяет принадлежит ли точка многоугольнику

```pascal
function IsInPoly(const ARegion: array of TPoint; const ASearchPoint: TPoint): Boolean;
var
  LPrevPoint, LCurPoint: TPoint;
  Li: Integer;
  DX, DY, StepX, StepY: Integer;
  Step: Double;
  Rotation: Double;
begin
  LPrevPoint := ARegion[0];
  Rotation := 0;
  for Li := 1 to Length(ARegion) - 1 do begin
    LCurPoint := ARegion[Li];
    DX := LCurPoint.X - LPrevPoint.X;
    DY := LCurPoint.Y - LPrevPoint.Y;
    StepX := LPrevPoint.X - ASearchPoint.X;
    StepY := LPrevPoint.Y - ASearchPoint.Y;
    if (StepX <> 0) or (StepY <> 0) then begin
      Step := (DX * StepY - DY * StepX) / (StepX * StepX + StepY * StepY);
      Rotation := Rotation + Step;
    end;
    LPrevPoint := LCurPoint;
  end;
  Result := (Abs(Rotation) > 5);
end;
```

Помогите идентифицировать этот алгоритм. Я не вижу, чтобы что-то подобное было описано в тех статьях, которые гуглятся. В итоге я не понимаю, работает ли код в принципе?

Тут, как я понял `(DX, DY)` - это вектор от предыдущей точки к следующей, а `(StepX, StepY)` от искомой к предыдущей. А что такое `Step` и `Rotation`?

Comment: `Result := (Abs(Rotation) > 5);` выглядит странно, сейчас попробую подобрать контпример.

Comment: `Step := (DX * StepY - DY * StepX) / (StepX * StepX + StepY * StepY)` — площадь треугольника делят на квадрат стороны. Зачем? Не понимаю геометрического смысла.

Comment: сдается мне этот код пытается суммировать углы наклона из точки в контур многоугольника, типа как стрелка часов идет из искомой точки в край многоугольника. Здесь `Step := (DX * StepY - DY * StepX) / (StepX * StepX + StepY * StepY);` - типа расчет унла между векторами, но верх похож на скалярное произведение векторов, но внизу должно быть произведение длин, а не просто квадрат длины одного из векторов. Наверное это от того, что надо посчитать тут не угода между векторами, а прирост угла в сравнении с предыдущим углом, я хз короче :) .

Comment: @tym32167 верх "похож" на vektornoe произведение векторов

Comment: Это и есть векторное произведение, площадь треугольника

Comment: Более устойчивый алгоритм - `ptinpoly` на основе подсчёта пересечений с лучом из данной точки. [Реализация на Delphi](http://delphimaster.net/view/8-1208862988)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, алгоритм неправильный.

Контрпример — квадрат со углами (1, 0), (0, −1), (−1, 0), (0, 1), проверяемая точка (0, 0).

В этом случае `(StepX * StepX + StepY * StepY)` всегда равно 1, и мы суммируем площади треугольников `OAᵢAᵢ₊₁`, которые складываются в 4, что меньше 5.

(Алгоритму, судя по всему, нужно дублировать начальную точку в конце.)

---

Насколько я понимаю, автор алгоритма хотел сложить ориентированные углы `AᵢXAᵢ₊₁` для всех `i`, эта сумма должна давать теоретически 0 для точки снаружи и 2π для точки внутри. Правильная реализация должна по идее выглядеть так:

```
DX1 := LCurPoint.X - ASearchPoint.X;
DY1 := LCurPoint.Y - ASearchPoint.Y;
DX2 := LPrevPoint.X - ASearchPoint.X;
DY2 := LPrevPoint.Y - ASearchPoint.Y;
S := DX1 * DY2 - DX2 * DY1; // ориентированная площадь, произведение сторон на синус
P := DX1 * DX2 + DY1 * DY2; // скалярное произведение, произведение сторон на косинус
if (S <> 0) or (P <> 0) then begin
  Angle := ArcTan2(S, P);
  Rotation := Rotation + Angle;
end;
```

и в конце сравнивать угол с `2 * PI`. Плюс дублировать начальную точку лучше в самом алгоритме. Не забудьте компенсировать погрешности вычислений: углы могут не сложиться в *ровно* 2π.

---

Ещё популярные алгоритмы:

1. Вычислять последовательно векторы сторон `AᵢAᵢ₊₁` многоугольника, и брать векторное произведение `AᵢAᵢ₊₁` на `XAᵢ` (`X` — тестируемая точка). Если у всех этих векторных произведений одинаковый знак (геометрически: точка `X` на пути вдоль каждой стороны всё время слева (или справа), то точка внутри. Алгоритм работает только для выпуклых многоугольников. (Возможно, его можно обобщить для произвольных многоугольников, подсчитав чётность смен знака, доказать с лёта не могу.)
2. Провести через точку `X` произвольную прямую (например, горизонтальную), и подсчитать точки пересечения с каждым из *отрезков*, составляющих стороны. Если слева (или справа) от точки `X` чётное количество точек пересечения (например, ноль), то мы снаружи, или нечётное, то внутри. Чтобы не разбираться со случаями, когда прямая проходит через вершину, можно выбрать не обязательно горизонтальную прямую, любую не совпадающую ни с одной из прямых `XAᵢ` (их конечное число). Это решение в духе теоремы о жордановой кривой, работает для любого несамопересекающегося многоугольника.

Comment: Так, а в коде сейчас увидел, что начальная и конечная точки, таки дублируются. Пока не понятно всегда-ли (код очень большой и кривой), но дублирование в одной из веток есть

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov: ну код всё равно не рабочий, первый же пример не прокатил. Ну такое.

Comment: Сейчас привел в чувство код и выяснилось две вещи: 1) в полигоне первая и последняя точка совпадает 2) если в полигоне меньше восьми вершин, то он отбрасывается. С такими уточнениями можно считать, что код рабочий?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov: Не-а, всё равно не катит. Вот полигон: `(0, -1)`, `(0.5, -1)`, `(1, -0.75)`, `(1.375, -0.25)`, `(1.5, 0.4375)`, `(1.28125, 1.1875)`, `(0.6875, 1.828125)`, `(-0.2265625, 2.171875)`, тестируем точку `(0, 0)`. Она внутри, но алгоритм возвращает false. (Я подбирал точки так, чтобы каждый step был 0.5.)